# Converting HTML element to string in JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to convert a html element created from a string back to the string after some modifications. But I get an empty string instead.

```
$('<iframe width="854" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gYKqrjq5IjU?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').html();
```

How can I do that another way?

Comment: cache the string ! or outerHtml indeed

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
var $html = $('<iframe width="854" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gYKqrjq5IjU?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');    
var str = $html.prop('outerHTML');
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS6by/)

Answer (score 39):

What you want is the outer HTML, not the inner HTML :

```
$('<some element/>')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: another way could be done by `$('<some element/>').prop('outerHTML')`

Answer (score 2):

`(document.body.outerHTML).constructor` will return `String`. (take off `.constructor` and that's your string)

That aughta do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a slight different approach:

```
//set string and append it as object
var myHtmlString = '<iframe id="myFrame" width="854" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gYKqrjq5IjU?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$('body').append(myHtmlString);

//as you noticed you can't just get it back
var myHtmlStringBack = $('#myFrame').html(); 
alert(myHtmlStringBack); // will be empty (a bug in jquery?) but...

//since an id was added to your iframe so you can retrieve its attributes back...
var width = $('#myFrame').attr('width');
var height = $('#myFrame').attr('height');
var src = $('#myFrame').attr('src');
var myReconstructedString = '<iframe id="myFrame" width="'+ width +'" height="'+ height +'" src="'+ src+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
alert(myReconstructedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just wrap it into another element and call `html` after that:

```
$('<div><iframe width="854" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gYKqrjq5IjU?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>').html();
```

note that `outerHTML` doesn't exist on older browsers but `innerHTML` still does (it doesn't exist for example in ff < 11 while it's still used on many older computers)