# jQuery Object to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a jQuery obj as;

```
var input = $('<input />', 
              {'type': 'text','name':currElmModelAttr, 'style':'width:100px' ,
               'data-model-id': currElmModelId, 'data-model-attr': currElmModelAttr,
               'class':'datePicker', 'value': $(this).html()}
             );
```

Can I use any method to convert it into the form

```
<input type="text".... />
```

So that I can directly say

```
$(this).html(aboveHTMLCode);
```

Comment: Yes, but why? You can use `.append()` instead of `.html()` to insert it, or if you need a copy, use `input.clone()`, like `$(this).empty().append(input.clone())`

Comment: actually i want to replace the existing html...kind of inline edit...div > input > div

Comment: cookie's comment + `input[0].outerHTML`

Comment: There is no HTML in the DOM. If you want to replace existing elements, then the `.empty()` method I added to my comment will do that. It's more efficient than serializing the element to HTML, and then parsing it back into a new DOM element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812510/converting-html-element-to-string-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string

Comment: Oh wait, are you saying that you want to remove the `input` element and show its HTML representation instead? Or did you only want to show its `value`? I think we need more detail.

Comment: `$(this).html($('<div>').append(aboveHTMLCode).html());`

Comment: so initially i have a label like 05/01/1984 ...on click i want it to be replaced with an input box with the same date value in it...

Comment: Using `$('<input />')` generates a new HTML Element. Its just a matter of adding it, via jquery or native js. So yes use any method to convert it to the form `<input type="text"...` etc unless you want a string?

Comment: @testndtv: Assuming your label is `this`, you can do `$(this).replaceWith(input)` if I'm understanding you correctly